# Ruby on Rails: Failed to open TCP connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tcp, server, connection, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri and I'm receiving this error

```
Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:41585 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 41585)
```

on this line of the code

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://www.instagram.com/p/BfaMpSuDTbn/'))
```

I should mention that I've run a license sever for registering Rubymine recently and it might have changed the system settings.

Full rails server log:

`` Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:41585 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 41585)):app/controllers/crw_controller.rb:7:in `index'
  Rendered /home/arman/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (19.3ms)
  Rendered /home/arman/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (13.8ms)
  Rendered /home/arman/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered /home/arman/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (69.4ms)
  Rendered /home/arman/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /home/arman/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /home/arman/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (7.0ms)
  Rendered /home/arman/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /home/arman/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (55.8ms)
  Rendered /home/arman/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (16.4ms)
  Rendered /home/arman/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.6ms)
  Rendered /home/arman/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (125.8ms) ``

Any thoughts?

Comment: I was wondering about the 127.0.0.1:41585, are you using somekind of firewall, vpn or port forwarding tools?

Comment: @Bambang I'm sure there is no firewall or vpn. But in fact rails sever is showing this error since I used a server license for registering RubyMine. There was a file called "dvt-jb_licsrv.linux" which I used it as a license server. After that although my browser Internet is ok, but rails can't make TCP requests

Comment: Does the same problem happen when you  run rails server outside the IDE?

Comment: @Bambang yes even on terminal. I'm wondering how can i undo configs that the license server made

Comment: There is no reason to put "Solved" in title, if a question was solved, please accept an answer and it will appear as solved for others.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it was because of my license server I used for registering Rubymine. Reinstalling rails solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error code says explicitly that your connection was refused. That means, that the Server didn't allow you to access the ressource.

In your case, the picture is most likely on a private account. You either have to provide credentials of a user with access to the picture or gather data from public sources.

Comment: @DaGroove seems like it was an internal error (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48885847/6886695)